# How to convert string cyrillic date into integer date

Tags: mysql, datetime, type-conversion

I have parsed data from open sources and stored dates as a string like:
'25 февраля 2018' (= 25 February 2018), but I would like to store dates like an integer: 20180225 to make it easier to calculate and create SQL extractions

As you can see date contains Cyrillic months and I tried to cast it into Date type but unfortunately, it retrieves NULL

The only thing, which I managed to do so far is to convert 25 февраля 2018 into 25022018 but I need opposite order year-month-day rather than day-month-year

I'm new in MySQL, could you please help

Thanks

Comment: You already solved the difficult part. `25022018` can be converted with [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: Used STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%dd%mm%yyyy') for 25022018. It retrieves NULL

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%d%m%Y')` - You can find all specifiers [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Oh.. Thank you very much